# how to use the new mozilla's console in xulrunner?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom, xulrunner

is there a way to embed the new firefox's console in a xulrunner application?

I always used to do so:

```
<iframe type="chrome" src="chrome://global/content/console.xul" flex="1">
```

but, I would love to use the new one if possible. I will mainly use it for JS debugging so also the scratchpad would be ok!

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, devtools are part of the browser app (aka Firefox).

Comment: is there a way to create a custom console logging only messages and errors from xul (hiding content's errors... like those happened in <browser type="content">) ?

Comment: I guess with a console service listener you can do the filtering.